# How can I monitor which page in the web browser is making a DNS request?

Tags: web-browser, dns, monitoring

I manage a Microsoft environment and I use FortiClient EMS for our endpoint security. That system is logging blocked requests to https://h.parrable.com. As best I can tell, this is *not* a malicious site per se but appears to be a service being used by third parties.

FortiClient only reports that "MS Edge" is the process that performed the DNS request. I know staff are not directly visiting this site so it's most likely being requested through some kind of embedded JavaScript.

What can I do on the workstation(s) to determine which website(s) is initiating this request? My only thought is to record the screen and then see what was happening at the time an event was logged.

My preference would be to have a log of DNS requests from the browser along with what's in the address bar at the time of each DNS request.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the Developer Tools for it. I don't use Edge, but Chrome and Firefox both have it. You can take a look at all the requests from inside the browser.

Comment: OK that's a great idea for this purpose. I'll try that.